# How to write a test that validates whether a function has successfully printed out a list of strings (specified in an array) to the screen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, assert

**Background/Context**

I am busy learning how to write modules (in my case: files containing a single module.exports function) and running them in the terminal (linux) using node.js.

Part of this process also requires that I write my own tests using the 'assert' module and run them using Mocha.

**What I need to accomplish**

I need to test whether a module taking in an array (list) of strings as a parameter is successfully printing out each string to the screen.

Printing out each string to the screen is not complicated.

**My code : module 'draw.js'**

```js
// draw.js
------------------

module.exports = function(arrayOfStrings) {
  
    arrayOfStrings.forEach(function(string) {
      
      console.log(string);
      
      });
  };
```

This successfully prints out each string to the screen. However, even though I know it works I am required to write test for it.

**The code should look something like this:**

```js
//draw_test.js
------------------

var draw = require('../draw');

var assert = require('assert');

describe('draw', function(){
  
  it("should pass through parameter ['hey', 'there'] and print out 'hey' and 'there' to the screen on separate lines.", function() {
    
    var result = draw(['hey', 'there']); // PROBLEM
    assert.equal(result, /*insert expected result here*/);
                 
  });
});
```

**The problem**

I have commented in where the problem lies in the code above.

The trouble comes in where I need to declare a variable called 'result' which will serve as the 'test' result against what I expect.

There are two problems:

a) 'result' will be undefined because draw(arrayOfStrings) prints to the screen using `console.log` and does not/should not `return` anything.

=> How do I solve this? I have spent hours researching and thinking but I have                  come up with no obvious solution.

b) I can't compare 'result' against any *one* thing because it needs to validate that *all* strings are printed to the screen. But in order for them to be printed to the screen individually requires a loop.

=> So how can the test verify that each string is printing to the screen?

I am sure that my two 'problems' above can be solved with one fix, but I can't seem to discover what that fix should be.

**Some more context : there must be something more**

I am certain I am missing something.

a) I was required to name this module 'draw.js' because I am supposed to use it to 'draw' things using characters to the screen. I have the feeling that I am supposed to do something more than 'console.log' here to print to the screen (for that is what 'printing to the screen' means to me).

b) I am assuming that when they say the function "takes a list of strings as a parameter and prints each entry in the list to the screen" that they mean each entry (or string) should be printed on a separate line.

c) I am supposed to be using this function (or module) called 'draw' in the next few tasks. Here are the names of the modules that I have to create with given directions:

**square_stars.js**

"Can draw a 4x4 square using the * character. Use the draw function you created above to display the results of the function on the screen. All subsequent functions that need to draw something on the screen should use the draw function. Why do you think we need the draw function?"

```js
// Please edit this to provide hint on how to approach!
```

**square.js**

"Takes a character as a parameter and draws a 4x4 square using it. Remember to use the draw function."

**square_param.js**

"Takes a character and dimensions as parameters, and can draw a square using them. Remember the draw function."

**tri.js**

"Can draw a triangle with a base of 4 using *."

```js
//Please edit this to provide hint!
```

**tri_char.js**

"Takes a character as a parameter, and can draw a triangle with a base of 4 using it."

**square_param_base.js**

"Takes a character and a base size as parameters, and can draw a square using them."

```js
//Please edit this to provide hint!
```

**diamond.js**

"Can draw a diamond shape using *. The center of the diamond should be 5 characters wide."

```js
// Please edit this to provide hint!
```

**diamond_base.js**

"Takes a character as a parameter, and can draw a diamond shape using it. The base of the diamond should be 5."

**diamond_char_base.js**

"Takes a character and a base size as parameters, and can draw a diamond shape using them."

```js
//Please edit this to provide hint!
```

The reason I am providing you with this list is not only because I foresee similar issues with those tasks as with this one, but also to give context. One of you might be able to tell me if what I am doing is appropriate for the tasks that lie ahead. And I truly do hope you will tell me whether I am on the right path or not.

I would also appreciate some hints (not answers) as to how I could approach the modules above.

But before you guide me in the right direction to accomplish the tasks, please tell me how I am supposed to configure a test using the 'assert' module that follows a similar layout as shown above to validate a function that prints to the screen (i.e. `console.log`) and doesn't `return` anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question about the `draw()` function. There's no code to check if the thing was printed to console, because almost everytime `console.log()` prints the text (except errors etc). If you really want to check if the variable printed out was an array, check if it's an array:

```
function draw(params) {
    // Don't continue if params are not an array
    if (!Array.isArray(params)) return;
    // If it's an array, do something here
}
```

To print a text to the page simply do `your_element.innerHTML = your_text`. To get through every part of the array use `.map()` function.

```
function draw(params) {
    if (!Array.isArray(params)) return;
    var inner = '';
    params.map(function(param) {
        inner += param + '<br>';
    });
    document.body.innerHTML += inner;
}
draw(['hey', 'there']);
```

### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt8Lwz6s/)

Why do I use inner variable? Because if you use `document.body.innerHTML += param + '<br>';` inside `.map()` function, remove the line above and below it and use draw function with array of for example 10000 elements, it will **slow down the page**, because JS sets innerHTML 10000 times, and with my code it sets the innerHTML of body only once.

---

About the `square()` function, I made one:

```
function square(character, size) {
    // If character is not a string, then set it's default value to '*'
    var ch    = typeof character == 'string' 
                    ? character : '*',
        // If size is not a number, then set it's default value to 4
        s     = typeof size == 'number' ? size : 4,
        inner = '', i, j;

    // Make a square
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++) { // Rows
        for (j = 0; j < s; j++) // One-line for
            inner += ch; // Prepare the one line
        inner += '<br>'; // After the end of the line add a linebreak
    }
    document.body.innerHTML += inner; // Set the innerHTML
}
square(); // Will print 4x4 square filled with '*'s

// Other examples:
square(-1, 10); // Will print 10x10 square filled with '*'s
square('&'); // Will print 4x4 square filled with '&'s
square('&', 16); // Will print 16x16 square filled with '&'s
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt8Lwz6s/1/)

---

About the triangle and diamond functions... Unfortunately it's not easy to do in my opinion.

---

Cheers

PDKnight